# Traduction de « jerry/jury-rigged » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En [anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/132868) on a l'adjectif « *jerry-rigged* » qui réfère à l'aspect improvisé/temporaire d'une chose, un mélange de « *jerry-built* » et « *jury-rigged* » suggère [*Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerry-rigged). Alors que [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/jerry-built) ne contient que « *jerry-built* » du côté britannique(voir aussi [*GD*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17046162)), *Collins* fait état d'une nuance entre l'anglais US vs. UK pour « *jury-rigged* »:

> [*British*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/jury-rigged)
>    (mainly nautical) set up in a makeshift manner, usually as a
>   result of the loss of regular gear
>
> [*American*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/jury-rigged)
>   rigged for temporary or emergency use

On peut imaginer quelque chose comme:

> This jerry-built house even contains a swimming pool with a water pump which is
>   jerry-rigged to use a lawm mower for power; there is evidence of jury-rigged repairs to appurtenances throughout.

Quelle est la traduction usuelle de « jerry/jury-rigged » et y a-t-il des distinctions à faire en ce qui a trait aux sens et emplois quand on traduit en général, et en particulier comme dans l'exemple ? Doit-on faire une adaptation selon la catégorie d'objets; y a-t-il une clé de traduction particulière à utiliser avec ces adjectifs ou c'est selon les cas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J'aurais tendance à dire que c'est une manière de dire "bricolé", dans le sens où ça a été improvisé. (bidouillé)
Une autre façon de dire, en français, serait "avec les moyens du bord".

En regardant un peu sur Internet, "jerry-" a une connotation péjorative, ce qui voudrait dire que, dans la phrase en exemple, c'est quelque chose de mal fait, bâclé. "jury-" suggère quelque chose de fait avec les moyens du bord, une solution temporaire mise en oeuvre pour arranger quelque chose à défaut de pouvoir faire mieux.

Comment: En guise de 1e jet : "Dans cette maison de fortune se trouve même une piscine avec une pompe bricolée pour utiliser une tondeuse comme source d'énergie. On y trouve des réparations ingénieuses/astucieuses (?) sur tous les objets." J'ai un peu plus de mal pour trouver une traduction fidèle à "jury-rigged" : il faut pouvoir montrer le côté improvisé mais astucieux de la réparation.

Answer (score 4):

Although I can only offer as reference little more than 1) my age (having been born before the first appearance in 1959 of the word “jerry-rigged”); 2) a link to a likewise unsupported, [Andru's zero-vote answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132868/jury-rigged-or-jerry-rigged/212001#212001) to the ELU question that you cite; and 3) my love of “real” jazz (i.e., the improvised kind that can never be played the same way twice), I am of the opinion that “jerry-rig,” with its pejorative “bâclé” connotation (as mentioned by Paul Picard) is nothing more than an erroneous, “[garbled](http://www.wordcourt.com/archives.php?show=2004-03-10)” version of “jury-rig,” with its wonderfully positive “improvisation” connotation (also mentioned in Paul’s good answer).

Therefore, based on my pedantic-like opinion of the term “jerry-rigged,” I’m going to conveniently transcribe the “jerry-rigged” portion of your example to read as “jury-rigged” and attempt to answer your question accordingly.

Perhaps again showing my age, our children grew up watching the tv show “MacGyver” with us and the title character of that show was undoubtedly the king of “jury-riggers,” and, although always ingeniuosly improvised, MacGyver’s work, IMO, was NEVER shoddy.  In English, the word “MacGyver” has even been coined as a transitive verb (to assemble or repair something by ingenious improvisation, using everyday items that would not usually be used for the purpose) and “jury-rig” is listed [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/MacGyver) as its sole synonym.

My French wife, when asked how she would describe MacGyver, the character, and his improvisations in French, immediately came up with the “le roi du ‘[Système D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_D)’,” with “D” meaning, depending on the audience, either "débrouiller" or démerder, from which one could get the adjective "débrouillard(e) (cf. démerdique?) to use in your example wherever “…..-rigged” is used.

On the other hand, the “jerry” part of “jerry-built” does legitimately imply shoddy workmanship (and, again without references to provide, I personally think it comes from the connection of the word “jerry” to “chamber pot” = “crapper” = crappy/shoddy workmanship), which makes the pejorative “bâclé” suggested by Paul a totally suitable translation of “jerry-built” in your example (although its use in the same sentence with “even” and “….-rigged” indicates to me that its author was born after 1959 and is a fan of neither improvisation, MacGyver, nor “real” jazz!) (cf. the expressioon: "[close enough for jazz](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/49/messages/56.html)" [last paragraph]).

Comment: Yes, the unlikely/ambiguous combination of the two notions in this context is what my next-to-last parenthetical tried to address. Personally I think "jerry"(poorly) should not be extended from its original connection with "built" (which however shoddily built, still implies finality) to a 'new,' 1959 association with the word "rigged," which to me implies something less than "final," even when the "jury" is [left] out. So, yes, changing everything to "jerry-" as mentioned in your comment to Paul would remove the verbal ambiguity, but rigging a mower to run a pump would still be ingenious,imo.

Comment: Well, I guess Papa Poule gave you all the precisions I missed. Haven't thought of "Système D" even though I watched a lot of MacGyver. Always good to learn things while trying to help !

Comment: @PaulPicard That's exactly how I felt when I read your good answer earlier this morning (I'd upvote it again if that were permitted). My wife did come up with "Système D" immediately as I related, but I think I "forgot" to mention in my answer that I first told/warned her that "bricolé", "improvisé", and "bidouillé" (my favorite, BTW) had already been taken by you!

Answer (score 1):

Cela me semble plus une histoire de style et de sonorité qu'une question de vocabulaire technique. Pourquoi donc ne pas faire de même en français, et se faire un peu plaisir? Cela ne saurait donc qu'être une solution personnelle; en tout cas, pour premier jet et sans connaître le reste de la prose de l'auteur, je proposerais:

> Cette maison *de bric et de broc* abrite même une piscine dont la
>   pompe à eau, *bricolée à la six-quatre-deux* pour utiliser une tondeuse
>   en guise de moteur; sur les dépendances alentour, *le système D et la
>   bidouille* laissent partout voir leur empreinte.